# Contextmenu right click in java get target name div variable

Tags: java, html, cgi

I have simple html5 cgi generated webpage for files but i need to have rightclick contextmenu with search option in google.

Every file div looks like this:

```
if [[ $file =~ \.jpg$ || $file =~ \.JPG$ || $file =~ \.jpeg$ || $file =~ \.png$ || $file =~ \.PNG$ || $file =~ \.webp$ || $file =~ \.bmp$ ]]; then
        {
        echo '<div class=''"'lightbox-file'"'' data-src=''"'$file'"'' data-sub-html=''"'$file'"''>'
        echo '          <div class="filemanager-photo">'
        echo '              <a href=''"'$file'"''>'
        echo '                  <img src=''"'./.tmp/thumb - $file.jpg'"'' />'
        echo '                  <div class='"'filemanager-photo-name'"'>'$filename'</div>'
        echo '              </a>'
        echo '          </div>'
        echo '</div>'
        } >> "$url_local_path"/.tmp/list_photo
```

Context menu script:

```
# Context menu
echo '      <script src="/js/context-menu.js"></script>                                                                         '
echo '      <script>                                                                                                                '
echo '        var items = [                                                                                                      '
echo "          { name: 'Pobierz', fn: function(target) { console.log('Pobierz', target); }},                                               "
echo "          { name: 'Udostepnij', fn: function(target) { window.open('//facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + window.location.href); }},                                         "
echo '          {},                                                                                                              '
echo "          { name: 'Google', fn: function(target) { window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + filemanager-photo-name??????????????????); }},                                "
echo '          {},                                                                                                              '
echo "          { name: 'Usuń', fn: function(target) { console.log('Usuń', target); }},                                           "
echo '        ];                                                                                                                    '

echo "        var cm1 = new ContextMenu('.filemanager-photo-name', items);                                                                  "

#echo "       var cm2 = new ContextMenu('.minimal', items, { className: 'ContextMenu--theme-custom', minimalStyling: true });      "

echo "        cm1.on('shown', () => console.log('Context menu shown'));                                                           "
echo '      </script>                                                                                                              '
```

What i should put here to get google proper keyword which is $filemanager-photo-name variable when i rightclick on photo link on my page?

```
echo " { name: 'Google', fn: function(target) { window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + filemanager-photo-name??????????????????); }}, "
```

Comment: How to pass div with name when i click on that div to java variable?

I think first i need to pass  div name variable to contextmenu list then i can use that variable in menu options

Answer (score 0):

/js/context-menu.js

```
!function(e, t) {
    "object" == typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module ? module.exports = t() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(t) : e.ContextMenu = t()
}
(this, function() {
    "use strict";
    !function(e, t) {
        void 0 == = t && (t = {});
        var n = t.insertAt;
        if (e && "undefined" != typeof document) {
            var i = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0], o = document.createElement("style");
            o.type = "text/css", "top" == = n && i.firstChild ? i.insertBefore(o, i.firstChild) : i.appendChild(o), o.styleSheet ? o.styleSheet.cssText = e : o.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e))
        }
    }
    (".ContextMenu{display:none;list-style:none;margin:0;max-width:250px;min-width:125px;padding:0;position:absolute;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.ContextMenu--theme-default{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.15);box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.15);font-size:13px;outline:0;padding:2px 0}.ContextMenu--theme-default .ContextMenu-item{padding:6px 12px}.ContextMenu--theme-default .ContextMenu-item:focus,.ContextMenu--theme-default .ContextMenu-item:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05)}.ContextMenu--theme-default .ContextMenu-item:focus{outline:0}.ContextMenu--theme-default .ContextMenu-divider{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.15)}.ContextMenu.is-open{display:block}.ContextMenu-item{cursor:pointer;display:block;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.ContextMenu-divider{height:1px;margin:4px 0}");
    var e = [], t = 0;
    function n(e, t, n) {
        void 0 == = n && (n = {});
        var i = document.createEvent("Event");
        Object.keys(n).forEach(function(e) {
            i[e] = n[e]
        }), i.initEvent(t, !0, !0), e.dispatchEvent(i)
    }
    Element.prototype.matches || (Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector);
    var i = function(n, i, o) {
        void 0 == = o && (o = {className: "", minimalStyling: !1}), this.selector = n, this.items = i, this.options = o, this.id = t++, this.target = null, this.create(), e.push(this)
    };
    return i.prototype.create = function() {var e = this; this.menu = document.createElement("ul"), this.menu.className = "ContextMenu", this.menu.setAttribute("data-contextmenu", this.id), this.menu.setAttribute("tabindex", -1), this.menu.addEventListener("keyup", function(t) {
            switch (t.which) {
            case 38:
                e.moveFocus(-1);
                break;
            case 40:
                e.moveFocus(1);
                break;
            case 27:
                e.hide()
            }
        }), this.options.minimalStyling || this.menu.classList.add("ContextMenu--theme-default"), this.options.className && this.options.className.split(" ").forEach(function(t) {
            return e.menu.classList.add(t)
        }), this.items.forEach(function(t, n) {
            var i = document.createElement("li"); "name"
            in t ? (i.className = "ContextMenu-item", i.textContent = t.name, i.setAttribute("data-contextmenuitem", n), i.setAttribute("tabindex", 0), i.addEventListener("click", e.select.bind(e, i)),
            i.addEventListener("keyup", function(t) {
                13 == = t.which && e.select(i)
            })): i.className = "ContextMenu-divider", e.menu.appendChild(i)
        }), document.body.appendChild(this.menu), n(this.menu, "created")
    }, i.prototype.show = function(e) {this.menu.style.left = e.pageX + "px", this.menu.style.top = e.pageY + "px", this.menu.classList.add("is-open"), this.target = e.target, this.menu.focus(), e.preventDefault(), n(this.menu, "shown")}, i.prototype.hide
    = function() {this.menu.classList.remove("is-open"), this.target = null, n(this.menu, "hidden")}, i.prototype.select = function(e) {var t = e.getAttribute("data-contextmenuitem"); this.items[t] && this.items[t].fn(this.target), this.hide(), n(this.menu, "itemselected")}, i.prototype.moveFocus
    = function(e) {void 0 == = e && (e = 1); var t, n = this.menu.querySelector("[data-contextmenuitem]:focus"); n && (t = function e(t, n, i) {
            void 0 == = i && (i = 1);
            var o = i > 0 ? t.nextElementSibling : t.previousElementSibling;
            return!o || o.matches(n) ? o : e(o, n, i)
        }(n, "[data-contextmenuitem]", e)), t || (t = e > 0 ? this.menu.querySelector("[data-contextmenuitem]:first-child") : this.menu.querySelector("[data-contextmenuitem]:last-child")), t && t.focus()
    }, i.prototype.on = function(e, t) {this.menu.addEventListener(e, t)}, i.prototype.off = function(e, t) {this.menu.removeEventListener(e, t)}, i.prototype.destroy = function() {this.menu.parentElement.removeChild(this.menu), this.menu = null, e.splice(e.indexOf(this), 1)}, document.addEventListener("contextmenu",
    function(t) {
        e.forEach(function(e) {
            t.target.matches(e.selector) && e.show(t)
        })
    }), document.addEventListener("click", function(t) {
        e.forEach(function(e) {
            t.target.matches('[data-contextmenu="' + e.id + '"], [data-contextmenu="' + e.id + '"] *') || e.hide()
        })
    }), i
});
//# sourceMappingURL=context-menu.js.map
```